# Restart a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to re-trigger a JavaScript function automatically after it has run once.

Scenario: I have multiple items on a page I want to share in a loop. Each time I share an item, I get a pop-up that prompts me to confirm the action. So far, my script shares each item successfully once. But after it shares all items, it stops.

This is the Javascript code I have so far. To trigger the sharing function, I have a button that triggers the `clickShareButton` function (which isn't included below).

```
function waitForElement(selector) {
  var element = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (element) {
      shareLinkCount--;
      element.click();

      if (shareLinkCount) { 
          setTimeout(clickShareButton, 10000); // Share a new item every 10 seconds.
      }
      else{
          element.click();
          clickShareButton(); // My intent here was to re-start at the first item after the script has shared all the items one time. This doesn't seem to work.
      }
  } else {
      setTimeout(waitForElement, 2000, selector); //When the pop-up window opens, wait 2 seconds to share the item.
  }
}

function clickShareButton() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.button1')[shareLinkCount].click();
  waitForElement('.button2');
}//Defines the function to share the item on the page. 

var shareLinkCount = document.querySelectorAll('.button1').length - 1; // Creates variable for identifying the 1st share, and then cycling through all elements with this style.
```

I was hoping this part would trigger the `clickShareButton` function to run again, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
  else{
          element.click();
          clickShareButton(); // My intent here was to re-start at the first item after the script has shared all the items one time. This doesn't seem to work.
      }
```

Comment: Are you indicating that your `else` block is never entered?  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?